# What can I use instead of onActivityResult in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

[Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrpCJ.png) What can i use instead of `onActivityResult` in `Fragment`?
i used this code on inCreate

> Kotlin

```
photo.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
```

i wanna receive its result such like that,but in fragment

> Kotlin

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        selectedPhotoUri = data.data
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
        val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
        photo.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
        if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return@onActivityResult
        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")
        ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                        uri = it.toString()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: But in Fragment what? What's happening, what's not happening, what's the problem?

Comment: i take a screenshoot of my problem once i clicked on the fragment,please have a look above

Comment: this code is running if i use Activity NOT fragment

Answer (score 0):

your stack trace says when calling `photo.setOnClickListener` the `photo` is null. your problem is not relevant to `onActivityResult` just set `photo` like this before calling `photo.setOnClickListener`:

```
photo = findViewById(R.id.photo_id);// replace photo_id with id of photo

photo.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
```

you said:

> this code is running if i use Activity NOT fragment

First you have to call `startActivityForResult()` from fragment to receive its result in that fragment.

Second when calling `startActivityForResult()` first `onActivityResult()` of Activity is called then `onActivityResult()` of fragment **BUT** if you have overridden the `onActivityResult()` of activity and not calling `super.onActivityResult()` the `onActivityResult()` of fragments **will not** be called

Thus do not override `onActivityResult()` from activity or if you have overridden it and also want the `onActivityResult()` of fragment to be called just call `super.onActivityResult()` in `onActivityResult()` of activity.

---

If you can not go this way you can simply move your code to an optional method of fragment then call that method from `onActivityResult` of Activity.